# Android studio external libraries does not show library module dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have library project that uses few third party dependencies like

```
api 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.genius:groupie:0.7.0'
```

I deploy this library project into private maven repo and use it on app module with dependency

```
implementation "a-group:a-artifact:0.1.2@aar"
```

Now the issue is that when I try running the app, I get build error saying

```
Error:(30, 52) error: package com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview does not exist
```

in one of the classes from library module. This dependency is not used by app module but only by the classes in library module.
When I look at external libraries from Project Structure I don't see dependency for circular ImageView or Groupie. However the pom file located at Maven server does list those dependency in library module.
I tried switching `implementation` with `api` but didn't work.

Shouldn't the external libraries in app project list the dependencies used by library module too?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this problem?